# Tail and strip unwanted content from each line

Tags: tail

I've got a log that contains data I don't need and want to tail it and strip the data so that this:

```
[Tue Nov 07 2017 14:44:51 GMT+0100 (CET)] INFO :CREATE
[Tue Nov 07 2017 14:44:51 GMT+0100 (CET)] INFO {:name=>"Michal's new org", :time_zone=>"UTC"}
[Tue Nov 07 2017 14:44:51 GMT+0100 (CET)] INFO :FINAL_ATTRIBUTES
[Tue Nov 07 2017 14:44:51 GMT+0100 (CET)] INFO {:name=>"Michal's new org", :time_zone=>"UTC", :sync_version=>1}
[Tue Nov 07 2017 14:44:51 GMT+0100 (CET)] INFO :CREATE
[Tue Nov 07 2017 14:44:51 GMT+0100 (CET)] INFO {:action=>"create", :id=>7, :sync_version=>0, :type=>"user_organization", :details=>{}, :user_id=>28,
```

becomes this:

```
INFO :CREATE
INFO {:name=>"Michal's new org", :time_zone=>"UTC"}
INFO :FINAL_ATTRIBUTES
INFO {:name=>"Michal's new org", :time_zone=>"UTC", :sync_version=>1}
INFO :CREATE
INFO {:action=>"create", :id=>7, :sync_version=>0, :type=>"user_organization", :details=>{}, :user_id=>28,
```

I've heard about `multitail` but the documentation didn't help.

Comment: What do you mean by “tail”? Do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
$ tail file.log | sed -e 's/^.*)]//'
```